# Taylor series $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ convergence

Tags: taylor-expansion

I needed the Taylor series for $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ in $a = 0$.

I started with $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin(x) $, used the existing $sin$ Taylor series and multiplied by $\frac{1}{x}$:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Then I need the convergence-ratio:

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\cdot x^{2(k+1)} \cdot (2k+1)!}{(2(k+1)+1)! \cdot (-1)^k \cdot x^{2k}}\right| = \dots = (-1)\cdot x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{(2k+3)(2k+2)}$$

This goes to $0$ as $k \to \infty$ so the function converges for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, the series converges for all $x$. Since you are taking absolute values, the $-1$ towards the end should not be there.

Comment: You are welcome. It was easy, you had done all the work.  There is a gap, which you probably are not expected to fill. The series converges for all $x$, done. But does it converge (for $x\ne 0$) **to** $\frac{\sin x}{x}$? There is some general theory that says that it does. You could also do it directly, by showing that the partial sums do converge to $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Details are slightly painful. But to repeat, it is likely not expected that you do it.